# Train and horseman velocity

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, physics, elementary-functions

This is a more or less easy exercise but there is one point I do not understand.

We have a train starting at $(0|0) $with velocity $v_t=20 m/s$ straight in the $y$-direction and a horseman at $H=(100|100)$ with velocity $v_h=15 m/s$

There are two questions now:

**1)** In which direction does the horseman need to ride to meet the train at the same time on the line of the train.

**2)** What is the minimum velocity for the horseman to meet the train? In which direction does he have to go now?

You can draw a picture and will immediately see two things (to solve 1):

$(y-100)^2+100^2=x^2$ where is y the lenght from $0$ to the meeting point $M=(0|y)$ on the $y$-axis and $x$ is the lenght fromthe horseman to the meeting point. We also see that $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{15}{20}$. Now we can solve the two equations and get $y$ and $x$, the direction is therefore $HM$.

For the second part I have $\frac{\sqrt{(y-100)^2+100^2}}{20}=\frac{x}{v_{min}}$. Now I want to get somehow an equation like $x_{1,2}=...$ where only $v_{min}$ appears. Setting the root inside to 0 will lead to $v_{min}$, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second, the distance the train covers is $y$ and the time is $\frac y{20}$.  The horse covers $\sqrt{(y-100)^2+100^2}$ in time $\frac {\sqrt{(y-100)^2+100^2}}{v_h}$.  Setting these equal we have $\frac y{20}=\frac {\sqrt{(y-100)^2+100^2}}{v_h}$ or $v_h=\frac {20\sqrt{(y-100)^2+100^2}}{y}$.  Now you can take the derivative with respect to $y$ and get home.

Comment: Thanks, do you think this has some relation with Apollonian circles?

Comment: @Alexander:  I'm not familiar with them.  After a glance at Wikipedia, nothing came to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the initial position of the horse, let $N$ be the nearest point to $P$ on the track, and let $M$ be the place where horse and train will meet. Let $\theta=\angle MPN$. Note that $PN=100$. Let $s$ be the speed of the horse.

The train will have travelled $100+100\tan\theta$, taking time $5+5\tan\theta$. In that time the horse travels through a distance $100\sec\theta$. It follows that 
$$(5+5\tan\theta)s=100\sec\theta.$$
Thus
$$\frac{1}{s}=\frac{1}{20}\left(\sin\theta+\cos\theta\right).$$
We want to maximize the right-hand side, given that $0\le \theta\le \pi/2$.

Equivalently, we want to maximize $(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^2$, which is $1+\sin 2\theta$, and reaches a maximum at $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$.